# Spring Boot JPA - Entity failing due to calling getter method

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-17

Since upgrading from Spring Boot 2.2.x to 2.6.x (and Java 11 -> 17), our entity classes are having issues with some repository methods. We use UUID for our database ids, but also have strongly typed ids in the domain layer for type-safety. DB is Postgres.

Example (with some extra annotations, which don't solve the problem):

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class User {
  @Id private UUID id;
  
  @Transient
  public UserId id() {
    return new UserId(id);
  }
}
```

Our repository class:

```
public interface UserJPARepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> { }
```

Fails below:

```
repository.deleteById(userId.id());
```

with error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.example.User. Expected: class java.util.UUID, got class com.example.CycleId; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.example..Cycle. Expected: class java.util.UUID, got class com.example.CycleId
```

The issue seems to be that JPA is using Reflection to determine that `public UserId id()` is the correct getter for the Id, but as this method converts the UUID to a UserId, it fails. Renaming the `id()` method fixes the issue, but this is not ideal.

Adding a breakpoint to my `id()` method, I can see the call originates from `JpaMetamodalEntityInformation.getId`:

```
if (idMetadata.hasSimpleId()) {
            return (ID) entityWrapper.getPropertyValue(idMetadata.getSimpleIdAttribute().getName());
}
```

The `Transient` and `Access` annotations don't help to resolve the issue.

Everything was working fine in Spring Boot 2.2. The upgrade has introduced the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository interface for `deleteById` requires an input parameter of type UUID, which is the ID type specified in your `extends CrudRepository...` statement.  You are trying to call the method and pass a UserId object instead. Also, as you already pointed out, your function name of id() does collide with a getter naming convention for the property *id*.

Here are a few different ways you could solve the problem:

- declare a deleteByUserId method on your repository interface
- alter your repository interface declaration to use the key type of UserId instead of UUID
- refactor your model to have an appropriately named getter and setter for the ID property to expose it

Comment: Sorry, should have included my UserId class. userId.id() returns a UUID (otherwise the code wouldn't even compile).

Comment: Gotcha. If you add a getId function to the User entity that returns the UUID, will reflection prefer that?